# Poisson point process characterized by inter-arrival times

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, poisson-process

Suppose $X_i$ are iid exponentials and $X(A) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{1}_{X_1 + \cdots+X_n \in A}$ for Borel set $A$. I have shown that $X$ is a random measure, and that $X(A) \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(|A|)$ where $|A|$ is the Lebesgue measure of $A$. I have also shown that for $A_1, \ldots, A_k$ disjoint intervals, $X(A_1), \ldots, X(A_k)$ are independent. But I need to show this for general Borel sets $A_i$.

We can extend to disjoint open sets by simply writing each open set as a union of disjoint open sets. But now what? How do we extend to all Borel sets?

Comment: Where you say "writing each open set as a union of disjoint open sets", I surmise that you mean "writing each open set as a union of disjoint open intervals". If you have any class of of sets for which you can say that for disjoint sets in that class, you have independence, then you can extend it do countable unions of members of that class in the same way. (And when you write an open set as a union of disjoint open intervals, you don't need more than countably many.) Now I wonder if something similar can be done with countable intersections. If so, we're almost done.

Comment: For countable intersections is it not the case that we can write the measure of the countable intersection as a limit of the measure of sets in our class? As long as the random variables in the two different limits are independent, the limits should also be independent. I fear, however, that we may be restricted to monotone decreasing intersections in this case.

Comment: $$ B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3 \cap \cdots = B_1 \cap \Big( B_1\cap B_2 \Big) \cap \Big( B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3 \Big) \cap \cdots $$ That is a monotone decreasing intersection. I.e. every countable intersection can be written as a monotone decreasing intersection.

Comment: You're right. We can extend to the case where we have different countable intersections/unions, with the sets in each intersection/union disjoint from the sets in another intersection/union. 
Seeing that we have some sort of closure under intersections and unions, I'm increasingly being drawn to the monotone class theorem...